getmongo nifi date filter issue
I am unable to use date related queries in getmongo , following simple query is working mongo but its not filtering anything in the getmongo and selecting the complete collection in nifi
{"createdOn" : {"$gt":{
"$date" : "2024-08-19T11:39:46.308Z"
}}}
in getmongo all the queries are wroking fine for mongo unless its related with date , i have tried using ISOdate and $date but nothing is working , the complete collection is being selected

{"$date":"2024-08-19T11:39:46.308Z"} is mongodb extended JSON.  I don't think many things outside of mongodb code will treat that as a date.  Try using the numeric epoch time in milliseconds, like ``{$gt: 1724110786308}`
